# Hibernate returns Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' exception. Could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a piece of code

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits(final Set<Integer> ids) {
    final Criteria criteria = super.criteria().add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
    final List<Fruit> fruits = this.list(criteria);  // throws SQLGrammarException
    fruits.forEach(this::initializeFruit);
    return fruits;
}
```

When empty set provided, it will throw exception in `this.list(criteria)`, 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' exception. Could not extract ResultSet

Any suggestions how can I prevent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is how JPA is designed

> There must be at least one element in the comma separated list that defines the set of values for the IN expression.

And the easiest way how to handle the erroneous situation you mentioned on having an empty list is to skip querying the database altogether because the condition is not supposed to match any entry anyway:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits(final Set<Integer> ids) {
    final List<Fruit> fruits;

    if (ids.isEmpty()) {
        fruits = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        final Criteria criteria = super.criteria().add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
        fruits = this.list(criteria);
        fruits.forEach(this::initializeFruit);
    }

    return fruits;
}
```

Comment: It isn't a JPA error but a SQL error, most SQL engines don't support an empty `IN` clause. Also isn't **the condition is not supposed to match any entry** an assumption? Maybe the OP wanted to return everything without limit.

Comment: Of course it's a JPA thing, JPA could as well specify that its implementations have to follow the same fall-back as I did but they chose to design their API the way that they expect a non-empty set and let their consumers handle potential errors. JPA could have also specified that passing in an empty set results in e. g. an Exception but they didn't.

Comment: And what would be a sensible default? Return nothing? Exclude the in? Put an empty `null`? What might be logical for you might not be for someone else who might expect the other way around. JPA only translate to SQL, sql does't allow an empty IN clause hence the SQL breaks. Just as it would if you would create an empty IN clause when writing plain SQL. But alas, that it probably a different discussion/topic all together.

Comment: I know what my sensible default would be as I only include an "in" restriction when I want to restrict the results. Putting in a hard-coded restriction where I expect no restriction on certain conditions is exactly the obfuscated way people write code that takes up every readers time understanding all the unnecessary complexity instead of writing code that is easily readable by being concise and clear.